# Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

My fabric version is 1.1.0-preview, the peer, orderer, configtxgen is newly generated.

when I execute the configtxgen tool:

```
configtxgen -profile SoloOrdererGenesis -outputBlock genesis.block 
configtxgen -profile mych -outputCreateChannelTx channel-artifacts/mych.tx -channelID mych
```

It generate the genesis.block and mych.tx with channelName is mych.

Then orderer start with genesis.block, I execute following:

```
peer channel create -f mych.tx -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mych
```

it throw the error,

> Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied

which step is wrong?

my configtx.yaml file is:

```
---
Profiles:
    SoloOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium4:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3
                    - *Org4
            SampleConsortium3:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3
            SampleConsortium2:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
            SampleConsortium1:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
    mych4:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium4
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
                - *Org4
    mych3:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium3
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3

    mych2:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium2
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2

    mych1:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium1
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
Organizations:
    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: orderer/msp

    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP
        ID: Org1MSP
        MSPDir: org1/peer/msp
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer.org1.example.com
              Port: 17051
    - &Org2
        Name: Org2MSP
        ID: Org2MSP
        MSPDir: org2/peer/msp
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer.org2.example.com
              Port: 27051            
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: solo
    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    Organizations:

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
```

Answer (score 26):

When I got this problem my solutions was pretty simple .. I had already started my network using

```
/byfn.sh -m up
```

forgot about it and was trying to start it first by generating the crypto and then using the same command.
The problem was resolved as soon as I first downed the old network using

```
/byfn.sh -m down
```

and started again with the same up command.

Comment: Most obvious solution yet everyone does not notice it.

Comment: The key here for me was adding the flags --volume --remove-orphans to my original command to remove containers, which was Docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml down
Thus the whole correct command was:
Docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml down --volumes --remove-orphan

Comment: this is the perfect solution

Comment: It is a great solution, but i can not use `./byfn.sh -m down` without removing  network `net_byfn`, because it is active. If someone did not resolve the problem with `./byfn.sh -m down`, try to restart your docker and remove `net_byfn` then follow the answer again.

Answer (score 6):

It could very well be a simple matter of the wrong path for a file. When you generated the `mych.tx` file, you wrote it to `channel-artifacts/mych.tx` but when try to create the channel, you left out the `channel-artifacts` directory. You could try `peer channel create -f channel-artifacts/mych.tx -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mych`

That said, I just had a similar problem with the same error. I was testing a newly created genesis block and crypto. In my case, it was the result of the previous crypto and channel being stored in a Docker volume from one of my previous tests. That may *not* be the case with you, since you said you are creating a new peer and orderer.

You can check on that by connecting to one of the peers (or cli container if you have one) with `docker exec -it <container name> bash` and then running `peer channel list`. If you get something like this back, then that's your problem:

```
root@4cf873123669:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer channel list
2018-04-05 14:09:40.734 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-04-05 14:09:40.734 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-04-05 14:09:40.739 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-04-05 14:09:40.740 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 004 Sign: plaintext: 0AAE070A5C08031A0C08A4DC98D60510...631A0D0A0B4765744368616E6E656C73
2018-04-05 14:09:40.740 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 005 Sign: digest: 93EFB49DD86ABB5568DE1E2C8FC53FA99AB52929AFA24D7B317C270DE8CDC80B
Channels peers has joined:
mych
2018-04-05 14:09:40.743 UTC [main] main -> INFO 006 Exiting.....
```

If you don't see the `mych` listed under "Channels peers has joined:", then my answer is not pertinent to you. (But may be to someone else!)

Here is how you would restore your local Hyperledger Docker instance to a clean state:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml down --volumes
```

The `--volumes` tells Docker to remove any volumes associated with the containers in the configuration file.

For good measure, I just wiped everything (*all* Docker containers and volumes - this was a test system) down to a blank slate and started the process all over:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml down --volumes
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker volume prune
rm genesis.block channel-artifacts/mych.tx
```

Once I removed those, and started the Fabric back up, I was able to create the channel without getting that error.

If it doesn't work last resort will be `sudo service docker restart` which will restart all the docker services like docker system, network and volumes.

Answer (score 2):

```
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel- 
artifacts/genesis.block -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
```

while creating the genesis block you need pass the syschannelname.

while creating channel use the  different channel name.

Eg: 
1.sysmych 
2.mych

Answer (score 0):

It would be clearer if you share the debug log of orderer. To enable debug add

```
- ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
```

in your docker compose file under orderer service, and start your network again. you can then print out the log using command

```
docker logs CONTAINER_NAME --details
```

I suggest to print the log before and after running the create channel command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Error got resolved as below

you may need to add

Go path also

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

echo $GOPATH
```

followed by `/byfn.sh -m down` if it is Up Earlier.
reference:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/prereqs.html

Comment: If you are using Golang 1.14 (used in Hyperledger Fabric 2.2), beware setting `GOPATH`. This may cause issues due to the newer Go modules system: https://dev.to/maelvls/why-is-go111module-everywhere-and-everything-about-go-modules-24k - so use another var such as `gopath` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the solutions on this page didn't work out for anyone then try removing your network from docker networks. View your docker networks by running `docker network ls` and remove your network by running `docker network rm <network-name>`.

Removing docker network worked out for me but I did this on a dev server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with the permission as well as network already being up( partially).

I had started with "./byfn.sh up" without using sudo , so i got *error* for first time.

Next, i did "sudo su" then ran "./byfn up", again i got *error*.

Referring to one of the answers here being a superuser i did "./byfn down" and then "./byfn up" now, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this issue many times, always use `docker volume prune` to solve it.