# ERROR CREATING HYPERLEDGER FABRIC CHANNEL

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I keep getting an error when creating a hyperledger channel

```
2018-12-15 10:52:07.687 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied
```

Please advise.
Funny thing though I only get this error when I specify -channelID when I'm creating the genesis block. But it always works whenever I omit it.

I'm using the below setting to generate the channel.tx and genesis.block, I've also added the crypto configuration file.

The configtx is:

```
Organizations:

  - &Main
    Name: Main
    ID: MainMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/blackbeard.com/msp

  - &Actual
    Name: Actual
    ID: ActualMSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/actual.blackbeard.com/msp
    AnchorPeers:
      - Host: peer0.actual.blackbeard.com
        Port: 7051

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  Organizations:


Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  OrdererType: solo
  Addresses:
    - orderer.blackbeard.com:7050
  BatchTimeout: 2s
  BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 10
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
  Kafka:
    Brokers:
      - 127.0.0.1:9092
  Organizations:



Profiles:
  OneOrgGenesisBlock:
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *Main
    Consortiums:
      SampleConsortium:
        Organizations:
          - *Actual

  OneOrgChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - *Actual
```

And the crypto-config as below:

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: Main
    Domain: blackbeard.com
    Specs:
      - Hostname: main

PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Actual
    Domain: actual.blackbeard.com
    Template:
      Count: 1
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

Comment: Please insert your code! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @FZs, I've updated the code above

Comment: I'm also getting some warnings when generating the genesis block and channel.tx: `WARN 003 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specifications for the application group in configtx.yaml
WARN 004 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specifications for the application org group Actual in configtx.yaml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly down the network with byfn.sh -m down and start it back up (Source :-[Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151804/error-got-unexpected-status-forbidden-failed-to-reach-implicit-threshold-of)). If this isnt the case please provide more information :)

Comment: Jason, I'm not using the 'BYFN' sample, so this fix didn't work for me. I created my own sample network using the configurations above.

Comment: Following your idea Jason, I removed all containers and volumes and for safe measure restarted docker, now I am able to get it working smoothly. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: Glad it helped!